# 50s or 60s movie similar to Invasion of the Body Snatchers

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I watched the original *Invasion of the Body Snatchers* over the weekend with my son -- but it was not the movie from my faulty memory. Hopefully you guys can help me work this out.

I remember a scene with a boy looking out his window at night and he sees meteors fall to Earth over the rise (maybe sand dunes?). For some reason I thought this was an iconic movie scene but I can't find it anywhere on Google.

At the end of the movie you think the good guys have won but one of the last shots is of a truck heading out of town on a mountain road with the back full of the alien pods.

I believe there were also pod people, and plants replacing people.

As far as I can recall these two scenes are from the same movie, but according to IMDB and Wikipedia there is no such version of *Invasion of the Body Snatchers*.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: Honestly, it feels like you are smooshing two movies together (I could be wrong, though).  The truck scene sounds like the original Body Snatchers.  But the boy scene sounds like Invaders.

Comment: I think @Beofett hit the target.  It's possible you could be confused because there's been three versions of the story on film by now.  But the last scene, the one of the truck, was in the original _Invasion of the Body Snatchers_.  The film was a response to the communist witch hunts of that time and the director was forced to tack on another ending -- framing the film as a flashback as the main character narrates.  It allows them to have an ending with someone rushing into the room saying, "We found the truck with all the pods.  They're destroyed," thus making people feel like they're safe.

Comment: I'll confirm the truck scene is from the 50's version of Body Snatchers, not the 70's version with Leonard Nimoy and Donald Sutherland.  Watched that the other week with my sons and I wanted the 50's version, the feel of it was better IMO.  The meteorite scene could be from any number of invasion films but its not Body Snatchers.

Answer (score 8):

Could it be "Invaders from Mars" http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0045917 ?

Comment: That's definitely the other well-known "people being replaced by duplicates" movie.

Answer (score 6):

The scene with the truck full of alien pods is definitely from the original [Invasion of the Body Snatchers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049366/) (although not from the [1978 remake](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077745/)).

The meteor scene sounds like it is possibly from [The Day of the Triffids](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0055894/)?